# How can I structure my DAG if one node always stays in a running state while another never executes?

Tags: python, flume, airflow-scheduler, airflow

The scenario is pretty straight forward. I have 3 tasks that I need to run:

- flume_task >> sleep_task >> http_task

Executing these tasks independently works perfect. If I start the Flume agent (source HTTP, sink HDFS) manually through CLI and then send a curl command the agent then dumps the received message into HDFS.

Like I said, manually performing each action through CLI works seamless.

Scheduling this process via an Airflow DAG however poses a challenge. I've tried constructing my DAG in several ways however to no avail. The main problem is that the flume task (BashOperator) stays in a running state and never ends. This makes sense. It shouldn't.

But then the DAG never goes on to the next nodes (sleep 30s -> send curl command).

- I've constructed a linear dependence (flume_task >> sleep_task >> http_task) - gets stuck at flume_task.
- I've constructed BranchingPythonOperator with

  - branch A = flume_task
  - branch B = sleep_task -> http_task.

This way Branch A skips the flume_task, branch B succeeds with sleep_task and fails with http_task. Failed http_task makes sense, no agent running.

- Then I've decided to separate at the root so flume_task is independent:

  - flume_task
  - sleep_task >> check_flume_status >> http_task

Providing my code for the last example that I think has the most logical DAG construction. I hope someone can shed some light onto this. 
I've read numerous resources online and I'm aware that Flume is [event-driven](https://tech.marksblogg.com/minimalist-guide-tutorial-flume.html), but I cannot understand what am I doing wrong with my Airflow script?

I'd greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import TaskInstance

# Defaults
default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 11, 11),
    'depends_on_past':False
}

# DAGs
dag = DAG('HTTP_2_HDFS', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='59 * * * *')

# Commands
flume_command = "flume-ng agent --name myAgent --conf conf --conf-file /home/hadoop/flume/conf/http.conf "

sleep_command = "sleep 30 "

http_command = "/home/hadoop/flume/hdfs_test/HTTP_2_HDFS.sh "

# Tasks
def check_status(**kwargs):
    flume_task_instance = TaskInstance(flume_task, datetime(2019, 11, 11))
    state = flume_task_instance.current_state()
    if state == "running":
        print("FLUME PROCESS RUNNING !!!")

flume_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='FLUME',
    bash_command=flume_command,
    dag=dag
)

sleep_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='SLEEP',
    bash_command=sleep_command,
    dag=dag
)

http_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='HTTP',
    bash_command=http_command,
    dag=dag
)

check_running_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='CHECK_FLUME_STATUS',
        python_callable=check_status,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
)

# Node Connections
flume_task
sleep_task >> check_running_task >> http_task

# branch = BranchPythonOperator(task_id='BRANCH', provide_context=True, python_callable=check_status, dag=dag)

# branch >> flume_task
# branch >> sleep_task >> http_task
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience using flume directly, so I apologize if some of these assumptions are off, but in my experience, airflow doesn't play well with long-running processes.

It seems like you might want a different design here. What if the http task is running by itself in a dag, on a 1-minute interval? Can it still talk to the flume agent and flush the way it's supposed to?

So flume runs independently and you don't need the sleep task because you are using the airflow scheduler to run at intervals instead.

We have an analogous set up for accessing kafka topics in airflow. Only the consumer runs inside of airflow. We've built wrappers around it to simulate "streaming" but it's really more like several overlapping micro-batches running to give the illusion of a stream.